# Disable field.hide in angular formly

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

The default hide directive with angular-formly is ng-if which can be configured via e.g. the formlyConfigProvider.

Currently all my fields should always be shown and I don't want to have unneccesary ng-if="!field.hide" checks rendered that can inpact the performance.

How can I tell formly not to use this check per field/form or globally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you set `hide-directive="ng-show"` in the formly-form

```
<formly-form    hide-directive="ng-show"></formly-form>
```

"**hide-directive**

Allows you to control the directive used to hide fields. Common value for this might be ng-show. It will be passed !field.hide. You can also specify this on a global level using formlyConfig.extras.defaultHideDirective = 'ng-show'"

http://docs.angular-formly.com/docs/formly-form

So you can either set it as I instructed or you can choose to edit it in the config on startup for all fields

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15135060)

Comment: It absolutely is the correct answer...I'd suggest you go use formly and find out for yourself, then come back and apologize to me.  I use it everyday at work, I think I'd know.   http://angular-formly.com/#/

Comment: when I was reviewing your answer it was not complied. you was edited your post after my comment. when ever post a answer then write full cause only one or two line answers may consider as a Comment and deleted from community members.

Comment: It was still correct, do you even know what angular-formly is?

Comment: It's great that I can set the hide-directive on a per form basis. But for some/all forms I don't want to use a hide-directive at all.

Comment: @Akusai you don't need to use it...that only happens when you set the `hideExpression` property inside the field.  Other than that it isn't active.  Even if you set it globally, you would still have to actually use it in the fields or fieldGroups for it to have any effect.  That is just an overall setting as to how it should behave when you use it.

Comment: Regardless if you're using `hideExpression` formly still renders `ng-if="!field.hide"` E.g. in the intro example http://jsbin.com/kunaho/47/edit you can inspect any input element and look at its `div formly-field` container and you'll see the ng-if. I'll probably use a workaround like `hide-directive="data-ignore"`. Where data-ignore does not exists.

Comment: It has almost no impact on performance, I have lots of them on some pages, and some extremely complex logic as well.  Have noticed very little in terms of impact in that manner.

Answer (score 1):

ng-if add and remove elements from the DOM, when you want to show and hide large number of elements it can be slow, insted you can use ng-show.
ng-show will only change the visibility of the element.

```html
<html lang="en" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
  <head>
    <script>
      var oModelesDep = [];
    </script>  

    <!-- Angular Material requires Angular.js Libraries -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/gowpres/resources/js/utils/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

    <!-- Angular Material Library -->
    <script src="https://www.weldpad.com/starterkit.js?containerId=60515"></script> 

    <script data-meta="61021" src="https://www.weldpad.com/sogettopanswerers.html?containerId=61021"></script>            
  
                
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-app="MyApp">
    <h4 ng-init="showchat = true">Your - Starter Kit</h4>
    <button ng-click="showchat = false">hide</button>
    <button ng-click="showchat = true">show</button>

    {{showchat}}

    <sogettopanswerers ng-show="showchat" tag="html">
      <div ng-repeat="qdata in listqdata.items track by $index" style="background-color: white;">

        <div class="well" style="overflow: auto;">
          <h2>
            <a href="{{qdata.link}}" class="question-hyperlink">

              {{qdata.title}}
            </a>

            <small>{{qdata.view_count}} Views</small></h2>

          <contentashtml ng-init="load()" content="qdata.body">
          </contentashtml>

          <div style="padding:15px;display: inline-block;vertical-align: top;">
            <p>Name: {{qdata.owner.display_name}}</p>

            <a href="{{qdata.owner.link}}">
              <img ng-src="{{qdata.owner.profile_image}}" alt="Description"/>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div style="display: inline-block;">
            <p>Created: <span am-time-ago="qdata.creation_date * 1000"></span></p>
            <p>
              Last Update:<span am-time-ago="qdata.last_activity_date * 1000"></span>
            </p>
            <p>
              Answered:{{qdata.is_answered}}
            </p>
          </div>
          <p>
            Answers:{{qdata.answer_count}}
          </p>

        </div>

      </div>
    </sogettopanswerers>    

  
  </body>
</html>
```

Look at the line:

```
<sogettopanswerers ng-show="showchat" tag="html">
```

and see how fast the response is.